# JavaScript sort alphanumeric strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a sort function that sorts yard names (which arte strings) alphabetically.

```
const sortList = (list, col) => {
    return list.sort((a, b) => {
        if (!b[col] && !a[col])
            return 0
        if (!a[col])
            return -1
        if (!b[col])
            return 1
        if (a[col] < b[col])
            return -1
        if (a[col] > b[col])
            return 1
        else return 0
    })
};
```

However sometimes, the yards have number in them and the sorting looks like this:
[image]

I have tried adding attr to a[col] and b[col] but it produced even weirder results.
Is there an idea on how to avoid this type of behaviour?

Comment: Can you give examples of other ways the yards are named? Right now, I would suggest `ParseInt(a[col].substr(5));` To just get the number, but I'm guessing that's not going to fix your problem.

Comment: You can remove the last 2 `if` and `if-else` blocks and replace it with: `return a[col].localeCompare(b[col], undefined, { numeric: true })`

Comment: @adiga thank you, that almost worked. I don't think it supports numbers then. and I have those as well

Comment: Please add the sample data for `list` with `col` properties.

Comment: You could use `String(a[col])` and `String(b[col])`. Or `a[col].toString()`

Comment: I meant I am trying to use the same function to filter a column that is all numbers -> name column is all strings (with numbers), but let's say age is all numbers [13, 45, 76]